# Maven: use specific test-classes of project A in project B

Tags: maven, junit, dependencies, project-structure

I have projects A and B where B requires A. Inside project A I have a utility-class UC that should only be available for JUnit-tests and, therefore, resides in `src/test/java` of project A. As long as I write tests in A I have access to UC. However, if I run Maven and want it to execute the tests in B, I get compiler errors since UC is not accessible in B.

Obviously Eclipse includes all classes in all source folders when it compiles something (i.e., it knows about UC when I write tests in B), while Maven removes all test-classes in the final version of A.

My question is this: what do I need to do to have UC accessible in B when I run its tests with Maven?

Please understand that I'm new to Maven and I think that similar questions have been asked. However, I can't convert what is written there into my problem and fix it.

*I hope it's clear what I'm trying to do...*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After looking some more I finally found a solution:

http://www.waltercedric.com/java-j2ee-mainmenu-53/361-maven-build-system/1349-maven-reusing-test-classes-across-multi-modules-projects.html <sup>1</sup>

I've seen this pattern occasionally on other questions, so I guess I just didn't understand it that way... Oh, well. *eyeroll*

<sup>1</sup> That original link stopped working. I [found it again on archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20100722020517/http://www.waltercedric.com/java-j2ee-mainmenu-53/361-maven-build-system/1349-maven-reusing-test-classes-across-multi-modules-projects.html) (don't mind the awkward layout).

Answer (score 2):

The maven-jar-plugin page - http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/usage.html - mentions two ways.  The simple approach is creating a test-jar artifact, and then refer to that.  (snippets blatantly copied from official page)

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

and then refer to it with the test-jar type and test scope in the projects that need it:

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>groupId</groupId>
      <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
      <type>test-jar</type>
      <version>version</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  ...
</project>
```

If you need to do this a lot you should most likely consider moving your test code to separate projects.

Comment: Thanks for leaving my answer alone and adding your own answer ;)

Comment: @sjngm I rolled back when I found that the instructions given in your answer differed from the official Maven documentation.  Classification is different from type.

Comment: thanks for your usefull working sample. In addition, please notice that there is an open bug : test-jar is not generated when tests are skipped ! that make me creazy for some minutes ;)
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MJAR-138

Comment: @boly38 For any non-trivial amount of test classes you should drop generating test-jars because it grows unwieldy.

Answer (score 0):

I have always found test-jars awkward. They're kind of peculiar, because they only get used once freshly deployed to the repository. Otherwise other projects do not see the changes. This is why I recommend creating just normal projects which you can use to put your test helpers into and then refer to them by using a test scope dependency.